# VS code Remote Development problem with SSH connection (Windows to Linux)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access, openssh, vscode-remote

I'm Currently trying to setup Remote developement environment with VS code.

I have installed Remote - SSH plugin and edited my .ssh/config file as below

Host ABC

```
User ubuntu

HostName xx.xx.xx.xx

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/filename
```

- It trowing an error by saying "An SSH Installation couldn't be found"

Local Machine - Windows
Host Machine - Ubuntu(Linux)

Please help on this matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an SSH tool in your host machine. Popular implementation of SSH protocol, OpenSSH is installed by default in Windows 10. First confirm if you have OpenSSH client by going to

```
Windows Settings >> Apps & features >> Optional Features
```

If not, install OpenSSH client through "Add a feature" option at the optional features page.

Mostly VSCode can pick the executable from common installation locations of the ssh.exe. If still not able to resolve, add the property below in VSCode settings

```
"remote.SSH.path": "your/ssh.exe/path"
```

like

```
"remote.SSH.path": "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH"
```

Comment: Hi sgX. in I have Windows 10 - 1608 version and it doesen't exist OpenSSH Feature in   >> Optional Features

Comment: Hi sgX. in I have Windows 10 - 1608 version and it doesen't exist OpenSSH Feature in   >> Optional Features.  I had downlosded OpenSSH seporately and now it's working as expected. and another mistake I have done. I have tried to connect with .ppk key as the IdentityFile. And I have converted to private key using puttyGen. It is working perfectly now. Thanks your great assistance

Answer (score 4):

Instead of installing OpenSSH, installing Git on Windows 7 also works because Git for Windows installs the SSH client. It ships OpenSSH with the package.

Comment: Installing Git for windows worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 10 - 1608 version and it doesen't exist OpenSSH Feature in   >> Optional Features.

I had downlosded OpenSSH seporately and now it's working as expected.

and another mistake I have done. I have tried to connect with .ppk key as the IdentityFile. And I have converted to private key using puttyGen. It is working perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. Openssh was not present so had to install OpenSSH from Windows Powershell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Then copied the path of ssh.exe to VScode settings. Ex:
"remote.SSH.path": "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\ssh.exe"
It worked perfectly.